# Best site to post R related questions

Tags: discussion

I've recently started doing most of my GIS-related work with R, especially since the `sf` package came out, as opposed to other more classic GIS clients (ArcGIS, QGIS...). It seems the "geo-R" world is still quite small and I've already run into several issues/questions but have been doubting where to post.

On the one hand, most R related questions are on Stack Exchange, and it seems there's where the language expertise is. On the other, these are questions about spatial data packages (`sf`, but also `raster`, `sp`...) and would seem more appropriate here.

Since [the current trend](http://strimas.com/r/tidy-sf/) seems to be to integrate spatial packages (like `sf`) into the data science workflow with other common R packages (`dplyr`, `ggplot2`...), that provides another argument in favor of posting on Stack Overflow.

Could anybody provide some good criteria to post on one site or the other? Would there be any way of unifying spatial R questions on one of the two site?

Comment: A third SE site handles many `R` questions, too.  `R` was developed to perform *statistical* calculations.  If your question requires statistical thinking or expertise to answer, it may be on topic at [CV](https://stats.stackexchange.com).  If you need help with general coding, interpreting an error message, algorithm design, etc., then [SO] is the place to ask. If the problem seems to reside in the use of a spatially-oriented package, then you might get a good reception here on GIS. For comparison: 2500 `R` questions have appeared on GIS (2.6%), 17000 on CV (14.5%), 225,000 on SO (0.9%).

Comment: @Andre You are, as always, free to adapt anything here for your own use.